# Unable to create a new remote session. (appium error)

Tags: java, appium, appium-android

I'm about running my appium automation on aws device farm, and when I'm doing

```
mvn clearn package
```

and the test starts, I'm getting an error. The error:

> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The instrumentation process cannot be initialized. Make sure the application under test does not crash and investigate the logcat output.

I did about 2 hours of searching in google - nothing help.
I'm checked if the JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME vars registerd, and they are.

Java code:

```
@BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
        dc.setCapability("reportDirectory", reportDirectory);
        dc.setCapability("reportFormat", reportFormat);
        dc.setCapability("testName", testName);
        dc.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.0");
        dc.setCapability("platform", "Android");
        dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "ce0318237d211b0f01");
        dc.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "com.sec.android.app.sbrowser");
        dc.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, ".SBrowserMainActivity");
        driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), dc);
    }
```

Pom.xml: https://pastebin.com/s88ViRTA 
Appium server log: https://pastebin.com/CU1MhdSr
Thank you for who will try to help,
Alon.

Comment: Try setting the capability - dc.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");

Comment: Can you provide the logcat output? The error says to look at that

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling uiautomator2.server:

```
adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server
adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test
```

This is the exception in your attached log:

```
ComponentInfo{io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner} from pid=17958, uid=17958 not allowed because package io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test does not have a signature matching the target io.appium.uiautomator2.server
```

source: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/10993

Answer (score 1):

Please set the following capability :
"automationName": "UiAutomator1"

You should be good.

Comment: what will be the impact of this. I mean changing from UiAutomator2 to UiAutomator1 will slow down the performance or anything else ?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the latest appium version

because your error shows
"Original error: The instrumentation process cannot be initialized. Make sure the application under test does not crash and investigate the logcat output."